How can I have a table wrap to new page before footer is reached?
I'd like to print a dynamically generated HTML table plus page footer.
So, I defined an HTML table and footer, like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>List</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{styleRef}}" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="tableDiv">
      <table class="songsTable">
        <colgroup>
          <col class="imageCol" />
          <col class="artistCol" />
          <col class="titleCol" />
          <col class="genreCol" />
        </colgroup>

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="4" class="genreHead">{{Genre}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="image"></th>
            <th>Interpret</th>
            <th>Titel</th>
            <th class="genre">Genre</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr class="loop">
            <td class="image"><img alt="" src="{{ImageRef}}" /></td>
            <td>{{Artist}}</td>
            <td>{{Title}}</td>
            <td class="genre">{{Genre}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <div>Brought to you by&br;<img id="logo" alt="logo" src="{{LogoRef}}" /></div>
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>

… and I'm using this CSS (excerpt):
body
{
  background-color: white;
  color: darkslategray;
  font: 12pt "Open Sans";
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

table.songsTable
{
  font-size: 100%;
  break-after: page;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.songsTable tbody > tr > td
{
  padding: 0 1ex;
}

footer
{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

footer > div
{
  padding: 1ex 3ex;
  margin-left: 50%;
  background-color: #1E3142;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 90%;
  border: .1em solid black;
}

@page
{
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

Unfortunately, the table rows don't wrap above the footer:


What style rules must be defined to have the table wrap above the footer?

dont use position fixed, use flex box. the footer will be placed a the bottom if the table is short.


body {
  background-color: white;
  color: darkslategray;
  font: 12pt "Open Sans";
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#tableDiv {
  flex: 1;
}

table.songsTable {
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.songsTable tbody > tr > td {
  padding: 0 1ex;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
}

footer > div {
  padding: 1ex 3ex;
  background-color: #1E3142;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 90%;
  border: .1em solid black;
}

@page {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{styleRef}}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tableDiv">
      <table class="songsTable">
        <colgroup>
          <col class="imageCol" />
          <col class="artistCol" />
          <col class="titleCol" />
          <col class="genreCol" />
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="4" class="genreHead">{{Genre}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="image"></th>
            <th>Interpret</th>
            <th>Titel</th>
            <th class="genre">Genre</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="loop">
            <td class="image"><img alt="" src="{{ImageRef}}" /></td>
            <td>{{Artist}}</td>
            <td>{{Title}}</td>
            <td class="genre">{{Genre}}</td>
          </tr>
         
   
         
           <tr class="loop">
            <td class="image"><img alt="" src="{{ImageRef}}" /></td>
            <td>{{Artist}}</td>
            <td>{{Title}}</td>
            <td class="genre">{{Genre}}</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="loop">
            <td class="image"><img alt="" src="{{ImageRef}}" /></td>
            <td>{{Artist}}</td>
            <td>{{Title}}</td>
            <td class="genre">{{Genre}}</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="loop">
            <td class="image"><img alt="" src="{{ImageRef}}" /></td>
            <td>{{Artist}}</td>
            <td>{{Title}}</td>
            <td class="genre">{{Genre}}</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="loop">
            <td class="image"><img alt="" src="{{ImageRef}}" /></td>
            <td>{{Artist}}</td>
            <td>{{Title}}</td>
            <td class="genre">{{Genre}}</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="loop">
            <td class="image"><img alt="" src="{{ImageRef}}" /></td>
            <td>{{Artist}}</td>
            <td>{{Title}}</td>
            <td class="genre">{{Genre}}</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="loop">
            <td class="image"><img alt="" src="{{ImageRef}}" /></td>
            <td>{{Artist}}</td>
            <td>{{Title}}</td>
            <td class="genre">{{Genre}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div>Brought to you by&br;<img id="logo" alt="logo" src="{{LogoRef}}" /></div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>




This doesn't work, particularly not for printing. The footer is not being displayed on every printed page using the flex approach.
